# Why doesn't Android Debug mode and Android Monitor work together

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug, android-monitor

Why do android studio close its monitor if I debug the application ?
I need to change database table once I get results while debugging and then again debug , but the process goes like android debug closes the monitor as soon I start to debug .

Answer (score 0):

just go settings => Build, execution, deployment =>instant run => uncheck 'Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on depoly'

Answer (score 0):

Drag the `Debug`tag from the left to the right.

[image]

[image]

All the labels can be handled like this.